# Add Security Properties to K8S Pod to Execute NSEnter

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I am using a pre-created image from Amazon registry. When I run the image I receive the following error:

> ```
> nsenter: failed to execute /tmp/test.sh: Permission denied
> ```

I set the security context of the pod to privileged and set the runAsUser to 1000

```
privileged: true
runAsUser: 1000
```

The error persists and I am not sure why.
Do I need to allow with SELinux specific syscalls?

Comment: What is test.sh? How did you build your dockerfile?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you are trying to execute the file `/tmp/test.sh` inside the container and this fails because of permissions. If this is the case, you could either try altering your build of the image to include something like `RUN chmod +x /tmp/test.sh` or you need to manually make sure to set the executable flag on the file (with `chmod +x /tmp/test.sh`). This is just a guess, because as other people have mentioned, the question does not include much details about the error.